# Video Transcoding and ffmpeg converter is not working : PHPVideoToolkit error

Tags: 7, files

I am trying to play `*.flv` using Video Module and FFMPEG Converter.
Whenever I upload any flv video I get the following message:

> `PHPVideoToolkit error: Execute error. It was not possible to encode
>   "C:\xampp\htdocs\Resonance\sites\default\files\videos\original\barsandtone_3.flv"
>   as FFmpeg returned an error. The error is with the video codec of the
>   input file. FFmpeg reports the error to be "Error while opening
>   encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as
>   bit_rate, rate, width or height".`

Installed Modules are:

- Video - 7.x-2.9
- Video.js - 7.x-2.3 - Version: 4.0.3
- Video transcoder: FFmpeg / avconv : git: c2dd5a1
- JW Player

All are installed correctly.

Configuration of Video Module:

Inside Player Tab of Video(admin/config/media/video/players), following has been configured:

[image]

A New FLV Preset has been created and added under Preset Tab of Video(admin/config/media/video/presets). Details are as follows:

Preset name: FLV Preset

Video output extension: FLV Flash Video

Video codec: H 263/H263-1996,H263+/H263-1998/H263 Version 2 (Not sure about Video Codec)

FFmpeg video preset: None

Video quality: None

Video speed: None

Dimensions: 640 x 360

Aspect mode: Preserve Aspect Ratio

When I am uploading the video from content type then it extract the thumbnail as follows:

[image]

After saving the video it shows the following message:

[image]

My gut feeling is that I am setting up wrong preset but I am not able to solve this problem.

Comment: I have the same problem, do you found any solution ?

Comment: What is the error message that you are getting in the "recent log entries"?

Comment: @F1234k Reported errors

    PHPVideoToolkit error: Execute error. It was not possible to encode "/var/www/html/raw-drupal-7.31/sites/default/files/videos/original/drop.avi" as FFmpeg returned an error. Note, however the error was encountered on the second pass of the encoding process and the first pass appear to go fine. The error is with the video codec of the input file. FFmpeg reports the error to be "Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height".

Comment: @zhilevan did you try to disable the two-pass encoding (in the Advanced Options)? Does it work without issues?

Comment: @F1234k where is it(advanced options)?

Comment: @zhilevan it's in your video preset's edit form: admin/config/media/video/presets/preset/%video_preset The option is a checkbox that reads: "Force one-pass encoding"

Comment: @F1234k I check it and try again but yet `    PHPVideoToolkit error: Execute error. It was not possible to encode "/var/www/html/raw-drupal-7.31/sites/default/files/videos/original/barsandtone.flv" as FFmpeg returned an error. The error is with the video codec of the input file. FFmpeg reports the error to be "Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height".
`
I try generated code in command line, it work correctly,I think problem is in module